# SonarTsPlugin report not showing any Issues on Typescript files

Tags: angular, typescript, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to analyze an angular project with SonarQube. My project contains both JavaScript and TypeScript files.

Whenever I am doing a sonar analysis issues on the `.js` files, they are getting generated but the issues on all the `.ts` files are showing `0`.

I am using

- Sonarqube - 6.2
- Sonar Scanner- 3.0.3.778
- Jenkins to build the SonarQube report
- SonarTsPlugin plugin to generate the report

The contents of my sonar-project.properties file:

```
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=Sonar-Test
sonar.projectVersion=2.0
sonar.projectName=Sonar-Test
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=/jenkins/workspace/Sonar-test-PA-Web/src
sonar.ts.tslint.projectPath=/jenkins/workspace/Sonar-test/tsconfig.json
sonar.exclusions=/jenkins/workspace/Sonar-test/node_modules/**
sonar.ts.tslint.path=/jenkins/workspace/Sonar-test/node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint
sonar.ts.tslint.configPath=/jenkins/workspace/Sonar-test/tslint.json
sonar.ts.tslint.rulesDir=/jenkins/workspace/Sonar-test/node_modules/codelyzer
```

I followed all the steps in [the official documentation](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin).
But still I am not able to see any issues for my `.ts` files.

Comment: So you can see the issues on the SonarQube server, but cannot see them in your PDF report?

Comment: No, I am not seeing any issues on the .ts files in my sonarqubeserver. All the issues generated on .js files only

Comment: if I run the command 'npm run tslint' separately the issues are getting generated. but its not working with sonar. Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Downgraded the SonarTS plugin.